# Can I place a file on c drive of server where my website is hosted?

Tags: c#, hosting

By security reason, can I place file on the `C:` drive of server where my website is hosted?

If yes then how I set and get path of the location to use on pages?

We can get file on root of website like this:

```
licFileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/LicenseFile/") + licFileName;
```

Can I set the path to local drive `C:` of server and also get? And how?

Atiq

Comment: Just set the path... licFileName = "C:/myFile.ext";

Comment: I don't think this question is 'Too localised', it's about putting a file on a server...

Answer (score 2):

```
licFileName = @"c:\" + licFileName;
```

But you need access permissions to C:, if it's not your server, it might be a problem.
I wouldn't do that if I were you.

It seems like you're trying to prevent web users from accessing `LicenseFile/`. 
Instead, you should block access to `LicenseFile/` using your web server configuration.

Comment: Can I place check on file (same like nobody can access .aspx.cs or web.config files on the internet)?